# Cassandra delete operation

Tags: php, sql, cassandra

Why there is no method to delete a row, or a column in Cassandra 'kallaspriit' for PHP?

Is this possible, to perform such an operation in Cassandra ?

Comment: delete a column like removing it from table or remove columns data in all rows?

Comment: delete column, that's remove column from only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the client directly:

$cassandra->getClient()->remove($key, $column_path, $timestamp, $consistency_level)

or

I implemented the missing function and submitted the code for integration.

You can find the code there: https://github.com/kallaspriit/Cassandra-PHP-Client-Library/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the contents in the harddrive will not be removed until passed the gc_grace time configured in the column. For single-node installations use `gc_grace = 0`.